# How to change autocomplete material UI background on textFiled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

Hi, I am trying to remove the background of autocomplete. but did not manage. I managed to changed color but now I can't see the text input.

the image above show the problem . as you can see its override on the label.

```
  input: {
    color: '#A5AEB3',
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        color:'#000000',
        backgroundColor: muiTheme.palette.background.default
      },
```

Comment: Please create a working example with the stying that you already have. You can use https://codesandbox.io for that.